# Where are the N and C-termini located in hemoglobin?

Tags: biochemistry, structural-biology

I am trying to locate the N and C terminus of hemoglobin and cannot tell if the C is at Val-1 and the N is Arg-141.

Answer (score 2):

The N-terminus has the lowest residue number, and the C-terminus has the highest residue number. When showing a sequence, it is given from N-terminus to C-terminus when writing left to right. The specific sequence depends on whether you are looking at the alpha or beta chain, whether you are looking at fetal or adult hemoglobin, and which organism you are looking at.